# What's wrong with the following C++ code involving input and string?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int temperature;
temperature celsiustemperature[4];

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter a start temperature in celsius: ";
    cin >> celsiustemperature[0];
    cout << "Enter an end temperature in celsius: ";
    cin >> celsiustemperature[1];
    cout << "You printed " << celsiustemperature[0] << " and " << celsiustemperature[1] << "." << " Is this correct?" << endl;
    char szYesOrNo;
    cin >> szYesOrNo;
    switch (szYesOrNo)
    {
        case "yes":
               cout << "win";
               break;
        case "no":
              cout << "winner";
              break;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the following code. Sorry for not adding comments; I want it to print `win` if the user inputs `yes` and `winner` if user inputs `no`.

Comment: What happens when you compile your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't compile, because `szYesOrNo` is a `char`, and you are comparing it with string literals in your `switch` statement. String literals are of type `const char[]`, which cannot be directly compared to `char`.

Use `std::string` instead of a `char`:

```
std::string szYesOrNo;
```

This will also force you to remove the `switch`, because `switch` cannot operate on a `string` value (also notice, that your `switch` does not have a `default` case, so it won't handle incorrect input). Just do it this way:

```
if (szYesOrNo == "yes")
{
    cout << "win";
}
else if (szYesOrNo == "no")
{
     cout << "winner";
}
else
{
    // Handle wrong input...
}
```

Comment: Gah, I need to practise my speed typing.

Comment: @sftrabbit: It's just pure chance, I probably got the notification a few seconds before you ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
char szYesOrNo;
```

This is a single character.

```
switch (szYesOrNo)
{
    case "yes":
```

This will compare the value of the single character with the **address** of the string `"yes"`, which isn't what you want.

Either input to a string, or compare chars.

To compare chars:

```
switch (szYesOrNo)
{
    case 'y':
```

To compare strings, you can't use a switch statement. You could use nested `if/else`:

```
string szYesOrNo;

if(szYesOrNo == "yes") {
    cout << "win";
} else if(szYesOrNo == "no") {
    cout << "winner";
}
```

You can use `==` when comparing a `string` to a `char[]` (which is what `"yes"` is). `string` makes sure the contents are compared rather than just the addresses.

Comment: I fixed the program, I think. I had no warnings or errors. Is there a way to simplify the program?

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch on a string.  Only on an integer-like type (ints, enums, chars, longs).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you declare a variable as `char szYesOrNo;` which can only hold ONE symbol, such as a letter, but then expect the character to enter a whole word. You should use a `string` to do this instead. When you fix that, you will need to use `if` statements instead of a `switch` statement to make decisions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `szYesOrNo` is a single `char` and so can only contain one character. When you do `cin >> szYesOrNo;`, you are only reading `y` or `n`.

Second, you're trying to use a `switch` statement to compare this single `char` to the string literals `"yes"` and `"no"`. This comparison doesn't make sense. The string literals are of type "array of N `const char`".

Instead, use `std::string` like so:

```
string szYesOrNo;
cin >> szYesOrNo;
if (szYesOrNo == "yes") {
  cout << "win";
} else if (szYesOrNo == "no") {
  cout << "winner";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

szYesOrNo is a character, so you cannot switch it in a case of "yes" which is a string ( 3 characters )